# When concatenating multiple strings, why does python add parentheses?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to concatenate 3 strings, but when attempting to do this the resulting string unexpectedly begins and ends with a parenthesis character.  Why would it add these if they were not characters within the source string variables?

I have attempted a number of different approaches:
1. Using the + concatenation
2. Using .format() string method

my code:

```py
startdate = '2019-05-08 11:18'
enddate = '2019-05-08 11:33'
user = 'usermcuserton@user.com'

mystring = ("({0}<= CreationDate <= {1}) AND Creator = '{2}'").format(startdate,enddate,user)
```

result is this:

```
print mystring
('(2019-05-08 11:18<= CreationDate <= 2019-05-08 11:33) AND Creator = '
 "'usermcuserton@user.com'")
```

Why are those parentheses added to the start and end of the string?

Comment: If you use `format`it doesn't add parenthesis. Anyway, i tried to run your code but it give me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: When declaring `mystring`, you  mixed single and double quotes!

Comment: @olinox14 - My example was incorrect (apologies).  can you give it another look?

Comment: i can not reproduce your problem... Are you sure you are using python3+? If so, you shouldn't be able to use the `print xxx` form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have wrong quotes in your code. and the print command is wrong. i ran the correct code, which i posted below, and it works fine. no extra paranthesis.

```
startdate = '2019-05-08 11:18'
enddate = '2019-05-08 11:33'
user = 'usermcuserton@user.com'

mystring = '({0}<= CreationDate <= {1}) AND Creator = 
{2})'.format(startdate,enddate,user)

print(mystring)
```

output:

(2019-05-08 11:18<= CreationDate <= 2019-05-08 11:33) AND Creator = '
 'usermcuserton@user.com)

EDIT: if you dont want these parentheses in the output either, then remove them from the string where you declare mystring.

```
mystring = '{0}<= CreationDate <= {1}) AND Creator = 
{2}'.format(startdate,enddate,user)
```

Comment: He said he doesn't want the parenthesis.

Comment: @dome these are the ones inside the quotes. he said he didnt want the ones that are showing outside the quotes in the output he mentioned

Comment: My apologies dome & shaheer.  I've amended my code to reflect what my original is.

Comment: I don't know, his code is so badly written that is hard to understand what's the expected output.

Comment: @JGraham which parentheses dont you want? the ones inside the single quotes or the ones outside the single quotes?

Comment: @ShaheerBinArif, thanks.  I have just now adjusted my posted question to reflect the result but it's not showing because it's requiring 'peer review'.  My actual output looks like this:  ('(2019-05-08 11:18<= CreationDate <= 2019-05-08 11:33) AND Creator = '
 'usermcuserton@user.com)')

Comment: @ShaheerBinArif - the parentheses outside of the string are what I don't want

Comment: @ShaheerBinArif - in your result, you can see that there is a parenthesis before the string begins and a parenthesis after the string ends.  if it's a string, why are these here?

Comment: @JGraham because in your code, you have added these parentheses inside the string. when you declared the MYSTRING variable, the second character is a parenthesis. i have put the correct string in the EDIT above.

Comment: @ShaheerBinArif - thank you for your help.  This was indeed the issue.